# eventID TypeError exception trying to get google calendar event

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, typeerror

I'm trying to create a script to search for a specific event in my calendar, but when I use the `service.events().get(calendarId='primary', eventId=event_id).execute()` method as the [docs](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get#python) shows, I get a TypeError exception in the `eventID` argument.

In my `event_id` variable there is the actual id of an event that I have saved previously on a database with the `events().list()` method.

In the docs it's specified that a string argument is necessary but if I `print(type(event_id))`, it returns as a string.
I already checked that there is an event with that has `eventID` as its id.

Am I missing something?

This is the traceback of the error:

```
File "path\to\project\venv\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 1019, in method
    raise TypeError('Got an unexpected keyword argument {}'.format(name))
TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument eventID
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About `service.events().get(calendarId='primary', eventId=event_id).execute()`, when `eventId` of `eventId=event_id` is `eventID`, an error of `TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument "eventID"` occurs. I thought that the reason of your error message of `TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument eventID` is due to this.

In this case, please confirm your script. When it's `eventID=event_id`, please modify to `eventId=event_id`.

But, in this case, when your `event_id` is an invalid value, an error of `Not Found` occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### Note:

- From `I'm trying to create a script to search for a specific event in my calendar`, if you want to retrieve the event list from a Calendar, you can also use the following sample script. This sample script is from [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list#python).

  ```
    page_token = None
    while True:
        events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for event in events['items']:
            print(event['summary'])
        page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
        if not page_token:
            break
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get#python)

  - When the sample script for python, you can see the following script.

    ```
      event = service.events().get(calendarId='primary', eventId='eventId').execute()
    ```

Comment: in my `event_id` variable there is the actual id of an event that I have saved previously on a database with the `events().list()` method.

Comment: @Bunz Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. My answer is for your error of `TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument eventID`. Can I ask you about this?

Comment: I’m sorry, I miss read your first reply about changing the eventId keyword from eventID (that apparently I wrote) to eventId, since they were very similar and didn’t actually read it carefully.  
I’ll let you know if this solves my problem, thanks in advance